# Simulating Start and Stop archive in Expression Encoder 3 SDK

Tags: c#, expression, expression-encoder

I would like to be able to start an encoding session and then like in Windows Media Encoder 9, start and stop recording my live stream while the encoder is still running. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the way I solved this was to create two separate LiveJobs and start each when I

A) Started the general encoder

B)Pressed Record

I also set the output formats for the two jobs as WindowsMediaBroadcastOutputFormat and WindowsMediaOutputFormat. One was for broadcasting and the other was for simply recording to a file on the desktop.